# Удаление уведомления через сервис Android

Tags: android, android-notification

В музыкальном приложении есть сервис `Service MusicService`. Он проигрывает трек и создает уведомление (ну как и во всех плеерах, с кнопками паузы, вперед, назад). Вот код:

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements Playable {
public static ArrayList<Track> trackList;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

public int playingPos, trackPos;
public boolean isRepeating = true;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    createChannel();

    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("TRACKS_TRACKS"));

    trackList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("TRACKLIST");

    trackPos = 12;
    prepareUpdater(trackList.get(trackPos));

    return START_STICKY;
}

/*Остальной код*/

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    notificationManager.cancelAll();   //Проблема здесь
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

    if(mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
}
```

Суть в том, что бы при остановке работы сервиса (закрытие приложения), уведомление удалялось (`notificationManager.cancelAll();`) в `onDestroy()`. И здесь происходят очень странные вещи, при отладке с первым запуском вроде как уведомление убирается, но второй и последующие запуски (уже не через студию) не дают нужного результата, и уведомление не убирается. Через раз устройство показывает, что таки ошибка есть. Вроде как дело в том, что это всё делается через сервис, но решения я так и не смог найти.

Comment: Как минимум `super.onDestroy();` нужно поставить после вашего кода в конец метода,  а не в начало. Запомните правило: в методах запуска супер вызывается первым, в методах остановки последним.

Comment: @woesss ну проблему это всё равно не решило(

Comment: @woesss и возвращаясь опять таки к `super.onDestroy();` . В другом таком же приложении, только где всё реализовано непосредственно через M-activity класс, я попробовал переместить `super.onDestroy();` в конец, и при закрытии приложения устройство показывает, что возникла ошибка. Но когда он стоял вначале, такой ошибки не возникало.

Comment: То что однажды у вас получилось так на значит что это правильно и, уверен, причина ошибки была в другом. Добавьте больше информации - как запускаете и останавливаете службу, переводите ли её в режим переднего плана (если это уведомление foreground service, то убрать его можно только после вызова `stopForeground()` или передав в этот метод параметр удаления. Так же мы не видим как вы настраиваете само уведомление и канал - какие там приоритеты и т.д., это тоже играет роль. И добавьте лог что ли в метод `onDestroy()` - вызывается ли он вообще?

Answer (score 0):

Ну ошибка скорее всего здесь

```
intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("TRACKLIST");
return START_STICKY;
```

Так как при `START_STICKY` Сервис при перезапуске вернет `intent = null`

Comment: Если бы `intent` и был нулевым, тогда сервис не смог даже достать Треклист. Тогда треклист, соответственно, тоже был бы нулевым, из-за чего приложение сразу и крашнется. Ну, мне так кажется, могу быть и не прав.